# On rails 5 db create, pg timezone error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg

I created a new rails app with 'gem pg' and rails 5.0,0 but once i want to run rake db:create, I run into this error

My psql version is 9.6.2

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: 
>   invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC"

I have tried setting in my application.rb file, my timezone

```
config.time_zone = 'Kuala_Lumpur'
```

and even adding this as well but all to no success

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Kinda frustrated and not sure what else to do.

anyone got a solution for this. much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

try below code for timezone in `application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Comment: i already mentioned tht i have done that and it is not working

Comment: @KingsleySimon have you tried `'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'`